# PHP socket inactivity does not work

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, freebsd

PHP on FreeBSD, a fragment of a TCP server code:

```
  protected function connected ($user) {
  //     stream_set_timeout($user->socket, 7200); // does not work: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php
    socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>7200, 'usec'=>0));
    socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec'=>7200, 'usec'=>0));
    socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1);
    socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_SOCKET, 256/*TCP_KEEPIDLE*/, 7200*1000);
    socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_SOCKET, 256/*TCP_KEEPIDLE*/, 7200*1000);
  }
```

But this code does not help: the connection is broken after about 5 min of inactivity.

You see that I want it break after 7200 sec of inactivity.

Please help!

It seems that I understand why `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` do not work: they are about read/write timeouts not inactivity timeouts. But why the rest doesn't work?

Don't suggest to "ping" it manually, this solution was not accepted by my boss.

Comment: What do you mean by "5 min of inactivity" ? Is this inactivity at the application level? Or at the TCP?  After `TCP_KEEPIDLE` is when the probing itself will start

Comment: if you want to disconnect after a certain amount of inactivity, just track activity yourself and close the socket when it hits your number.   These options are for how to keep the socket alive or for detecting if the other side has silently disappeared.

Comment: Are you sure that `TCP_KEEPIDLE` is used at `SOL_SOCKET` level, and not at `SOL_TCP` level?

Comment: @Ayak973 http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/ says they're on SOL_TCP

Comment: `socket_set_option($user->socket, SOL_TCP, 256/*TCP_KEEPIDLE*/, 7200*1000);` - `PHP Warning:  socket_set_option(): unable to set socket option [22]: Invalid argument in /home/vhosts/israelinfo/php-lib/WebSockets/orders-notify.php on line 41`

Comment: @Ayak973: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/ - "the second one must be `SOL_SOCKET`, and the third must be `SO_KEEPALIVE`"

Comment: @porton : I think i didn't understand what you want to achieve. If you really want to close the socket when you have a read/write inactivity of 7200secs, `TCP_KEEPIDLE` is not the way to get it work, you'd better follow @xaxxon suggestion, _track activity yourself_